# how to use jquery to creat self-closing label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I tried this:

```
$('<input class="inputName" type="text" />').appendTo($('body'))
```

but it turns out

```
<body><input class="inputName" type="text"></body>
```

Is there a way to creat the proper self-closing label?

Comment: Have you defined a proper doctype?

Comment: Which tool are you using to get the markup of your `<input>` element? (since you're adding it to the page dynamically, it should not be visible in the page source). HTML syntax allows some elements to only have a start tag, and maybe that tool uses that convention to render markup.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi       I'm using firebug with FF4

Comment: I observe the same behavior as you with Firebug and Firefox 3. I suspect that's only a side-effect of the tool, since the `<input>` element still works perfectly. There are other quirks, e.g. Firebug renders `<span />` as `<span>     </span>` in jsFiddle result frames, which is also quite weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is in fact correct.
Ensure your DOCTYPE is XHTML.

**Edit:** You don't have to worry about any of this since the code won't pass through validators anyway (validators do not execute javascript).

Comment: I'm using xhtml 1.0 transition DOCTYPE. Should I use 1.0 strict?